# Load two columns in a combo box

Tags: vb.net

I have a combo box and I want to fill two columns from sql server database. My code is:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select hospno,hospno + '--- ' + name as pn from Patient order by hospno", cnn)
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable()
da.Fill(dt)
If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    cbohospno.ValueMember = "hospno"
    cbohospno.DisplayMember = "pn"
    cbohospno.DataSource = dt
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Empty")
End If
```

While running, combox is showing `name` instead of `hospno`. How can I show `hospno` in combobox?

Comment: WebForms / WPF / Windows Forms / Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

Set the DisplayMember to be "hospno" and you should be fine. 
DisplayMember is the one that is shown, ValueMember is the value you get if you get the combobox item value.